# What is the coordinate system, projection, and Geoid for geocoding in ggmap api?

Tags: r, geocoding, ggmap

What is the coordinate system, projection, and Geoid for geocoding ggmap api?

Answer (score 0):

Web Mercator, also known as Google Web Mercator, Spherical Mercator, WGS 84 Web Mercator or WGS 84/Pseudo-Mercator.